# How do I fix "Sudo commands will not succeed by default" on chromeOS Crosh Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo, google-chrome-os

I have been trying to install SeaBios for Ubuntu, and all of them say I need to use
Crosh Shell, every time I try to use it though it says "Sudo commands won't succeed by default" how can I fix this message to use sudo commands in Crosh Shell Terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no "official" fix for this, but you might want to look into https://github.com/chromebrew/chromebrew/pull/8832 As of 11/15/2023, it has not been merged yet, but you can install Chromebrew by running

```
exec bash --init-file <(curl -Ls git.io/vddgY)
```

Inside the VT-2 shell (also known as Frecon).

Then you can install crew-sudo locally by running

```
CREW_REPO=https://github.com/supechicken/chromebrew CREW_BRANCH=crew-sudo crew update
```

(Also in VT-2 after installing Chromebrew)

After that, make sure the daemon is running:

```
crew-sudo --daemon
```

Then exit VT-2

```
(Ctrl-Alt-{F1/Left arrow/Back})
```

And open Crosh

```
(Ctrl-Alt-T)
```

And then type

```
shell
```

Now you are able to execute sudo commands in Crosh, but you need to replace

```
sudo
```

with

```
crew-sudo
```

Example:

```
crew-sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin
```

Useful sources / sites:

[Chromebrew home page](https://chromebrew.github.io/)

[Chromebrew GitHub page](https://github.com/chromebrew/chromebrew)

[Crew-sudo GitHub page](https://github.com/supechicken/crew-sudo)

I really hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Do what crosh tells you to. You can access the VT-2 shell with these keys:

```
(Ctrl-Alt-{F2/Right arrow/Refresh})
```

Then login with the username `chronos`.

Then you will be able to use any `sudo` commands you like.